# How is it possible for two random variables to have same distribution function but not same probability for every event?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

It is completely out of the world for me to hear that such a case exists. I was shocked and could not develop any intuition as to how it is possible. It also breaks my understanding (intuitive) of the distribution function.

Here is the actual paragraph where this was given: 
[image: Casella and Berger Statistical Inference]

Comment: I assume you are referring to real valued continuous random variables?

Comment: It makes no sense to me, either.  Where did you hear this?

Comment: @MattSamuel You can actually define distribution for non-continuous real valued functions, as long as you are OK using measures instead of functions.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith The words "continuous" in "continuous random variable" and "continuous function" are completely unrelated, actually. Saying a random variable is continuous just means it has a probability density function.

Comment: @MattSamuel But you can have probability density functions for discrete random variables as well.  You just have to use "generalized functions."

Comment: Do you have an example of two random variables having the same distribution but giving different probabilities for the same event?

Comment: @zoli no, but I read this in a book (statistical inference by Casella & Berger) which gives a reference to a book Chung 1974, page 27.

Comment: Yes, these are two i.d. random variables. Can you produce two events for which the probabilities don't agree?

Comment: The quotation describes a sigma algebra, $B^1$, which seems to contain all the events that we would normally ever be interested in. Someone came up with a "pathological" example in a _different_ sigma algebra that (I assume) contains a lot of events that are not in $B^1$ and that most people would not care about. There may very well be something about those extra events that does not fit our intuition at all. The important thing is that the kind of events we care about, on which we build all the usual facts of probability, _do_ fit our intuitive understanding of probability distributions.

Comment: Yes. "if probabilities are defined on a larger class of events" (be careful while reading). However If $X,Y$ ahs teh same distribution then $P(X\in B)=P(Y\in B)$ $\forall$ $B\in \mathbb{B}$. As $[-\infty,x)$ is a Borel set we've $F_X(x)=F_Y(x)$ $\forall$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your information, here is the relevant quote from 
page 27 of *A Course in Probability Theory (2nd edition, Academic Press, 1974)*
by Kai Lai Chung. He has just finished constructing the probability 
measure $\mu$ with distribution function $F$.

> There is one more question: besides the $\mu$ discussed above
>   is there any other p.m. $\nu$ that corresponds to the given $F$ in the same
>   way? It is important to realize that this question is not answered
>   by the two preceding theorems. It is also worthwhile to remark that
>   any p.m. $\nu$ that is defined on a domain strictly containing ${\cal B}^1$
>    and that coincides with $\mu$ on ${\cal B}^1$ (such as the $\mu$ on ${\cal L}$
>   as mentioned above) will certainly correspond to $F$ in the same way, and 
>   strictly speaking such a $\nu$ is to be considered as distinct from $\mu$. 
>   Hence we should phrase the question more precisely by considering only 
>   p.m.'s on ${\cal B}^1$.

Here p.m. means probability measure, ${\cal B}^1$ are the Borel sets 
on the real line, and $\cal L$ is the $\mu$-completion of ${\cal B}^1$.

Comment: This quote works. The correspondence is unique only if the sigma algebra in question is the Borel sets on the real line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to stick my neck out and assert that *the quotation is nonsense*:

> ... it is possible for two random variables to have the same distribution function but not the same probability for every event.

It is nonsense because it does not make sense to say that a random variable "has a probability for an event". Once a probablity space is given, every event *has a probability* in itself (that's what the probability measure is for) -- and there's no role for a random variable in determining that probability.

---

What the quote appears to *try* to say is that $\mathbb R$ can be made into the sample space of a probability space in more than one way that gives the identity function (viewed as a random variable) the same distribution, but whose probability measures are not identical.

This can happen if the two probability measures are defined on a larger $\sigma$-algebra the algebra of Lebesgue-measurable sets, and assign different probabilities to some events that are not Lebesgue measurable.

Unfortunately, an example of this cannot be given explicitly; constructing one requires the Axiom of Choice. (Without AC it may be that all subsets or $\mathbb R$ *are* Lebesgue measurable and so their probabilities are given by the distribution).

In any case, it is confusing and misleading to describe this possibility as being about "two random variables" without further qualification, because that phrasing usually implies that the two random variables are defined on the same probability space (which makes the claim nonsense, as argued above).

Comment: We _do_ typically like to define more than one random variable over $\mathbb R$ in many probability exercises. But your point about non-measurable sets is a good one--that seems a likely candidate for all kinds of counter-intuitive results.

Comment: (Hmm... actually it is conceivable that it's enough for the two measures to disagree on some subsets that are Lebesgue measurable but not Borel. I'm not completely sure whether a distribution would fix the probabilty of such sets).

Comment: @DavidK: Then the usual formal underpinning, as far as I'm aware, is to say that the sample space $\Omega$ is not $\mathbb R$ but something with a richer structure, and $\mathbb R$ is merely the _range_ of each of the several random variables. An "event" is then a measurable subset of $\Omega$, not of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: OK, technically there is no such thing (in the usual theory) as a variable defined over $\mathbb R$, only over a $\sigma$-algebra which may consist of subsets of $\mathbb R$. And I can't recall ever looking at any such algebra that wasn't just some kind of Borel sets. So I assume whatever they did in the 1974 paper is beyond anything I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** By Lebesgue-Stieltjes-Correspondence, there is a one to one correspondence between the probability law $P_X$ when $X$ is Borel measurable and the c.d.f $F_X$. I guess what the text meant is that we could have a random variable $Y$ being measurable to a richer sigma algebra, say, Lebesgue measurable sets than the Borel sets so that the correspondence breaks down.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be the underlying probability space. Consider random variable $X$ and $Y$ defined on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ with the following properties

1. $X^{-1}(B)=Y^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{F}$ for all Borel sets $B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.
2. $X^{-1}(C)\notin \mathcal{F}$ and $Y^{-1}(C)\in \mathcal{F}$, where $C$ is the famous subset of Cantor set that is Lebesgue measurable but not Borel measurable $C\in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R})\setminus \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

This way we have a Borel-measurable but not Lebesgue measurable random variable $X$ and a Lebesgue measurable random variable $Y$. Recall that distribution function $F_X$ are induced by the law of $X$
$$
P(X\in B),\quad B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
It follows that $F_X=F_Y$ so $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution functions.

However, $P(Y\in C)$ is a nonnegative real number whereas $P(X\in C)$ is not defined. Thus the probability (law) of the Lebesgue measurable but not Borel measurable set $C$ differs for $X$ and $Y$.

A tentative construction of such $X$ and $Y$:

1. Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be $([0,1],\mathcal{L}([0,1]),\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Let the range of $X$ and $Y$ be $([0,1],\mathcal{L}([0,1]),\lambda)$ also.
2. Let $\phi(x)$ be the Cantor function. Define $X$ by setting
   $$
   X^{-1}(x)=\phi(x)+x.
   $$
3. Let $C$ be the Cantor set and $\tilde{C}\subset C$ be the Lebesgue measurable but not Borel measurable set.
4. By Vitali's Theorem, associate with $X^{-1}(C)$ a nonmeasurable subset $W\subset X^{-1}(C)$. The construction of $\tilde{C}$  (Royden, Real Analysis 4th Edition p.50) gives the following condition
   $$
   X(W)=\tilde{C},\quad X^{-1}(\tilde{C})=W\notin \mathcal{L}([0,1]).
   $$
5. Define the bijective transformation $S:\mathcal{L}([0,1])\cup\lbrace W\rbrace\rightarrow \mathcal{L}([0,1])\cup\lbrace W\rbrace$ such that
   $$
   S(X^{-1}(C))=W,\quad S(W)=X^{-1}(C),\quad \mbox{otherwise}.
   $$
6. Define $Y$ by setting
   $$
   Y^{-1}=S^{-1}X^{-1}.
   $$
7. Then for any $B\in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$, $B\neq W$ so $S^{-1}(B)=B$ and
   $$
   Y^{-1}(B)=S^{-1}X^{-1}(B)=X^{-1}(B).
   $$
   Property 1 is satisfied.
8. For $\tilde{C}\in \mathcal{L}([0,1])\setminus \mathcal{B}([0,1])$, we have
   $$
   X^{-1}(\tilde{C})=W\notin \mathcal{L}([0,1])
   $$
   but
   $$
   Y^{-1}(\tilde{C})=S^{-1}X^{-1}(\tilde{C})=S^{-1}(W)=X^{-1}(C)\in\mathcal{L}([0,1]).
   $$
   Property 2 is satisfied.

Comment: How is that an example of the situation claimed by the quote. $X^{-1}(C)$ and $Y^{-1}(C)$ are _different_ events (if they were the same event, the probability measure would have to assign them the same probability, since it is a function from events to probabilities), but the quote claimed some sort of situation where the _same_ event can somehow have _different_ probabilities.

Comment: It's also not clear to me how you can define $X$ and (in particular) $Y$ by specifying what the _preimages_ of particular sets are going to be. How do you know that specification is realized by any actual function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$? In particular there is no guarantee that $S$ will match any map $\Omega\to\Omega$. And how is $S$ bijective if $S(X^{-1}C)=S(W)=W$ yet $X^{-1}(C)\ne W$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: For you first question, I am guessing that the events in the text are respect to the laws, i.e. $P_X(C)\neq P_Y(C)$ where $C$ is the event. In most applications, $C$ is the event that we can talk about not $X^{-1}(C)$. For you second question, $S$ is defined as a mapping between the sigma algebras $\mathcal{L}([0,1])$ and $\mathcal{L}([0,1])$ where $S^{-1}$ is the inverse operator not the preimage.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I agree that my definition of $S$ is sloppy. Consider the mapping $S: \mathcal{L}([0,1])\cup\lbrace W\rbrace\leftrightarrow\mathcal{L}([0,1])\cup\lbrace W\rbrace$ such that $S(X^{-1}(C))=W$, $S(W)=X^{-1}(C)$, and $S(A)=A$ otherwise. This mapping certainly exists and you can verify it is bijective.

Comment: x @Xiao: But in order to define $Y$ you need to dive a definition that determines what $Y(\omega)$ is for each particular $\omega\in\Omega$. It is not enough to specify an $S$ between the $\sigma$-algebras -- that does not necessarily correspond to any map $[0,1]\to[0,1]$. And I don't agree that $C$ is an event -- an "event" means a measurable subset of $\Omega$, not a subset of the range of a random variable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I agree with your comment on whether such $Y$ as a function can exists. I am trying to show that such an idea is conceivable instead of giving a serious construction. About whether the Cantor set $C$ is an event, it definitely is. The exercise of defining c.d.f. is all about turning the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ into the probability space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}, P_X)$, something we can work with in practice. So $C$ is an event, a set in the sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}$ of the probability space in $\mathbb{R}$ that we can measure using $P_X$.